# Sql query: select latest row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables like this:

table info:

```
4 columns:
-mmsi (pk)
-name
-type
```

and table position_history

```
4 columns:
-mmsi (fk)
-latitude
-longitude
-timestamp (//datatype: timestamp without timezone)
```

position_history example:

```
-----mmsi----latitude-----longitude------timestamp------
-----------| -----------|-------------|----------------
    1001   |   34.3454  |     123.343 | 2014-04-07 03:37:00
    1001   |   24.5443  |     123.343 | 2014-03-07 14:23:00
    1001   |   14.1049  |     123.343 | 2014-02-07 18:12:00
    1001   |   54.2355  |     123.343 | 2014-01-07 02:00:00
    1002   |   34.3454  |     123.343 | 2014-04-07 03:37:00
    1002   |   24.3454  |     123.343 | 2014-03-07 03:44:00
    1002   |   14.3454  |     123.343 | 2014-02-07 15:37:00
    1002   |   54.3454  |     123.343 | 2014-01-07 12:32:00
```

and info:

```
 -----mmsi------name---------type--------
-----------| -----------|----------------
    1001   |   dsg      |     abc
    1002   |   cvv      |     xyz
```

**How can I query return results like this ?**

```
mmsi-----name-----type------latitude-----longitude------update_time
1001     dsg       abc       34.3454      123.343      2014-04-07 03:37:00
1002     cvv       xyz       34.3454      123.343      2014-04-07 03:37:00
```

Comment: You table info seems only to have 3 columns

Comment: Why did you tag this with `mysql` **and** `postgresql`? Are you using both DBMS?

Comment: No, just forum ask 5 tag to post question, and both DBMS use sql language:)

Answer (score 0):

Simple inner join will do it

```
select p.mmsi, i.name, i.type, p.latitude, p.longitude, max(p.update_time)
from position_history p inner join info i
         on p.mmsi=i.mmsi
group by p.mmsi
```

OR

```
select p.mmsi, i.name, i.type, p.latitude, 
         p.longitude, p.update_time
from position_history p inner join info i
         on p.mmsi=i.mmsi
where p.update_time in (select max(update_time) from table1
                         group by mmsi)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efc24/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from info 
  join (
      select mmsi,
             latitude,
             longitude,
             timestamp,
             row_number() over (partition by mmsi order by timestamp desc) as rn
      from position_history
  ) ph on ph.mmsi = info.mmsi and ph.rn = 1;
```

Or using `distinct on` which might be a bit faster:

```
select *
from info 
  join (
      select distinct on (mmsi)
             mmsi,
             latitude,
             longitude,
             timestamp
      from position_history
      order by mmsi, timestamp desc
  ) ph on ph.mmsi = info.mmsi;
```

---

btw: `timestamp` is a horrible name for a column. For one because it's also a reserved word and secondly because it doesn't document what the column contains: a "start date"? an "end date"? a "due date"? a "registration date"?